# Sass listen to live changes and compile files (on server with multiple websites)?

Tags: node.js, npm, sass, gulp, debian

The "deployment process" in our company (if you can even call it that) is that you usually (not always) make the site locally, then upload it to the server and after that do all changes on live server (yep...).

I am trying to push SASS in our company, but my boss basically told me that if there isn't a way for it to *autocompile after a change has been made on the server*, I can just throw away all my work reworking our styles to SASS and go back to pure CSS.

Here is folder structure sample of our server (we do have multiple sites running on same machine, they're all in separate sub-folders, but not all of them have frontends):

```
var/www/our_system/project_name1/web-frontend/frontend_name1
var/www/our_system/project_name1/web-frontend/frontend_name2
var/www/our_system/project_name2/web-frontend/frontend_name1
var/www/our_system/project_name3/web-frontend/
```

The *frontend_name**X*** contains a *style* folder which contains folders *scss* and *css* (where I want to autocompile contents of *scss* into the *css* folder).

So, the question again:
Is there a way, to have SASS permanently watch over any sass file changes and compile them to a css folder relative to the sass folder the compiled file was in (as my boss doesn't want to run watch command for every single website)? Also, it would be amazing if it could also run the CSS through Autoprefixer.

Thanks.

Ps.: We are using our own custom CRM/CMS written in PHP, there are no other frameworks etc. Front-ends are also written in PHP and HTML (no react, node, anything of sorts). Our server runs on Debian Jessie (and for PHP we use Apache).

Ps.2: Please, do not tell me that we are doing it wrong etc. **I KNOW**, but I can't do anything about it.

---

Edit:

I got my boss to try and install Gulp on our server to take care of this, but the installation itself actually failed.
The node was installed fine, same with npm (well, I think it threw some warnings, but got installed), but gulp just threw warnings and errored out (it installed fine globally, but died when installing for the project)...

The new question is, is the gulp way to go?
All we need is **something that autostarts** and keeps **watching all scss files** and **parses them when they change**.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the server your production server?  Do you use source control ? Do you use any continuous integration platform ?

Comment: @karthick Its our production server. We do not have a dev server. We do stuff locally on our PC's. Basically. When we work on our core product, that always goes to gitlab and gets manually pulled to the server. But when its comes to the customers custom edited (or new) stuff, well, that is live coded / edited on the server. Only few customer sites are on our gitlab... Thing is, I know this is really, really bad practice, but I can't do anything about it, I am not in charge and never will be, but I am at least trying to push some innovation to this company and this would help me bring SASS in.